# Normal Operator surjective

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I have difficulty proving:

If $T$ is a normal operator in a Hilbert space, $T$ is surjective if and only if $T^*$ surjective.

Please give me some help. Thank you.

Comment: Is $T$ assumed to be bounded?  If so, $T$ is actually invertible, hence so is $T^*$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Nice observation!

Answer (score 1):

Some strong hints:

1. For any normal $T$, show that the kernels of $T$ and $T^{\ast}$ coincide.
2. Relate the ranges of $T$ and $T^{\ast}$ to their respective kernels (there is a standard theorem about this).

Note that you have to assume that $T$ is a closed operator, which I hope is not an issue because it's typically not appropriate to use the term "normal operator" unless the operator is closed.